# Surface integral of the hemisphere $z^2 = 16- x^2 - y^2$

Tags: calculus

solve the surface integral $\iint_S z^2 dS$

$z = \sqrt {16-x^2-y^2}$

$dS = 4/\sqrt {16-r^2} $

$4\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4 ((16-r^2)/\sqrt {16-r^2})rdrd\theta$

What am I doing wrong with my integral setup? I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the hemisphere, we can Use spherical coordinate system $r(\theta,\phi)=4$.

The surface integral become $$\int_sz^2dS=\int_sz^2||{r_\phi}\times{r_\theta}||{d\phi}{d\theta}$$

where $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}2$

here, $$z=4\cos\phi$$ $$||{r_\phi}\times{r_\theta}||=16\times\sin\phi$$
so the integration becomes,$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(4\times\cos\phi)^2\times16\times\sin\phi{d\phi}{d\theta}=\frac{256\pi}3$$

As you can see $r$ doesn't vary in this calculation.